# How do I find the bug in this insertion code?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

My insertion code below has a bug.

How do I find the bug?

And are there any examples where the bug causes an incorrect sorting?

```py
    def insertion_sort(_A,n): # _A[0..n-1]
        for j in range(1,n):
            key = _A[j]
            i = j-1
            while i>0 and _A[i]>key:
                _A[i+1] = _A[i]
                i = i-1
            _A[i+1] = key
```

Comment: Should be `while i >= 0`  instead of `i > 0`. You can figure this out yourself by proper debugging...

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the element at index = 0.

Replace `while i>0` with `while i>=0`.

### Example:

> _A = [9,3,4,1]

Your code will give `[9,1,3,4]` as output.

While it should be `[1,3,4,9]`.

### Correct Code

```py
def insertion_sort(_A,n): # _A[0..n-1]
    for j in range(1,n):
        key = _A[j]
        i = j-1
        while i>=0 and _A[i]>key:
            _A[i+1] = _A[i]
            i = i-1
        _A[i+1] = key
```